# How to implement a SQL Server query which has several join conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to implement this query but I can’t figure out why I am not getting the result.

Here are the descriptions:

Lets say I have a table call: `TableAct`

```
Acct#   Date                    WithdrawAmt         DepositAmt
!24455  2012-11-19-00.00.00 1245.77                 200.50
125577  2011-02-12-00.00.00 100.98                  578.00
```

Another table `TableCustomerOrd`:

```
ID# COrder# CustID  Ord_Description  VendorType
124455  7712AS  123 1AAA             Permanent
125577  9914DL  346 1BBB             Partial 
...     UK1234  111 2HJ5             Permanent'
,,,     FR0912  567 5LGY             Partial
```

Then `TableCustomerDtls`:

```
CustID  Descriptions    Delivery    Address        ZipCode
123     1AAA_BLUESHARE  SUCCESSFUL  222 Main St 97002
346     1BBB_CHASE          DECLINE         40 West Side    97122
111     2HJ5_CITIBANK   SUCCESSFUL  …….         …….
567     5LGY_VANGURD    DECLINED        ----            -----
```

And table `DelivaryFlight`:

```
   FlightOrder#   FlightCustID      FlightDt
   7712AS           123    2011-9-29-00.00.00
   9914DL           346    2010-11-2-00.00.00
   UK1234           111    2012-4-1-00.00.00
   FR0912           567    2012-9-11-00.00.00
```

I want to update `TableAct` on the following conditions:

1. `TableAct. Acct# = TableCustomerOrd.ID#`, `AND`:
2. `TableCustomerOrd. CustID = TableCustomerDtls.CustID` and at the same time, `TableCustomerOrd.Ord_Descriptions` field should match with `TableCustomerDtls. Descriptions` field anything before `“_”` . Therefore `‘1AAA’, ‘2HJ5’` etc. `AND`:
3. `DelivaryFlight.FlightOrder# = TableCustomerOrd.COrder#`, `AND`: `DelivaryFlight.FlightCustID = TableCustomerOrd. CustID`. Also `TableCustomerDtls. Delivery = ‘SUCCESSFUL’` AND:

   ```
    DelivaryFlight.FlightOrder# = TableCustomerOrd. COrder#
    AND DelivaryFlight.FlightCustID = TableCustomerOrd. CustID
    Also TableCustomerDtls. Delivery = ‘DECLINED
   ```

Then I want to compare: `elivaryFlight.FlightDt >  DelivaryFlight.FlightDt`.

Basically I need to match table `DelivaryFlight` columns `FlightOrder#, FlightCustID` with `TableCustomerOrd`.

Moreover `TableCustomerDtls` column `Delivery` to `ck` for `delivary` status such as `‘DECLINED’`.

And `‘SUCCESSFUL’` condition and compare `‘SUCCESSFUL’ FlightDt` with `‘DECLINED’ FlightDt`.

Here's my query but please help me to understand, I am sure this could be done in a better way.

The query is not working:

```
     Update
     Set …
    FROM TableAct AC
    Join TableCustomerOrd CustOd
    ON AC.Acct# = CustOd.ID#
    Join TableCustomerDtls CDtls
    ON CDtls. CustID = CustOd. CustID
   AND (CustOd.Ord_Descriptions =
       Left(CDtls.Descriptions, LEN(rtrim(CDtls.Descriptions))))
   JOIN DelivaryFlight DF
   ON DF.FlightOrder# = CustOd.COrder#
   AND DF.FlightCustID = CustOd.CustID
   AND CDtls.Delivery = ‘SUCCESSFUL’
   JOIN DelivaryFlight DF2
   ON DF2.FlightOrder# = DF.COrder#
   AND DF2.FlightCustID = DF.CustID
   AND CDtls.Delivery = ‘DECLINED’
   WHERE DelivaryFlight. FlightDt >  DelivaryFlight. FlightDt
   AND DepositAmt > 100
```

Your Help will be monumental 'cause my project due end of this week.
    Thank you

Comment: I'm really not understanding this: `WHERE DelivaryFlight. FlightDt >  DelivaryFlight. FlightDt`

Comment: Do not use # in fieldnames, it is almost always best to avoid the use of symbols in fieldnames. In the case of # if you happen to use it as the first character, SQl server is going to think you have a temp table not a fieldname.  And please spell delivery correctly. That is the kind of thing that will drive maintenance programmers crazy so best to get in better habits from the start.

Comment: Beth Thanks yes those are typo

Answer (score 0):

If I have a complex query like this, I start by creating a "simple" select which produces only the rows to be updated.

It should also return both the update values and the pk for the updated table

It is then (relatively) straight forward to (inner) join this with the table to be updated and do the update remebering to only update matching rows by including

```
WHERE tblTobeUpdated.pk = SimpleSelect.pk
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi,  Thanks to all of you but here is my query and those were typo

Comment: I think you need to break you query down and test your join and conditions one by one. You look as if you are using a sub query and the clearest examples I've seen are http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html We dont have your data. All the other guidance here is good, but its part of learning fix issues that you develop teechniques in breaking problems down. I tend to write my queries a parameterised ones with go followed by exec myquery params as "in line" tests,  then pressing f5 in SSMS runs and tests all in one.

Comment: Ian,   Thanks Please take a look all the tables above, this query needs to match DF.FlightOrder# = CustOd.COrder#
   AND DF.FlightCustID = CustOd.CustID
   AND TableCustomerDtls.Delivery  = ‘SUCCESSFUL’
  Not only this also needs to match
  DF2.FlightOrder# = DF.COrder# 
   AND DF.FlightCustID = DF.CustID
   AND TableCustomerDtls.Delivery  = ‘DECLINED’
So I am doing to separate JOIN conditions on the DeliveryFlight table. 
Any other way I can implement it? Is it a good choice? Moreover please assist me to make this query work.

Comment: Hello All,  Please Help Me to Solve This Query...Many Thanks

Comment: You can nest your queries: I'll do it as a response because its difficult to wrie code in a comment

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to look at this in depth but I suspect you at least want to fix:

```
  WHERE DelivaryFlight. FlightDt >  DelivaryFlight. FlightDt
```

This is a condition that can never be met.

You probably want:

```
  WHERE DF. FlightDt > DF2. FlightDt
```

it is also useful with these complex queires for an update to be able to see the records that would be updated, so I usually do something like this:

```
Update
     Set …
--Select *
    FROM TableAct AC
```

Then instead of running the update, I run just highlight and run the part that starts with select to see the results and don't test the update until I am sure I am selecting the records I want to select and that the values I will be replacing are correct.

Comment: Thanks but could you please explain in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking your query down, heres a query I wrote today, test each part separately

```
SELECT
    Employee
    , Reference
    , Payroll
    , [Hours] / 60 
    [Hours]
    , [Days]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Employee
        , Reference
        , Payroll
        , SUM( Duration ) AS [Hours]
        , AvailableID
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            RequirerID
            , Duration
            , RTRIM( COALESCE(MA.MemberLastName, '') 
                + ' ' + COALESCE(MA.MemberFirstName, '')  
                + ' ' + COALESCE(MA.MemberInitial, '')) Employee
            , COALESCE(MA.Detailref1, '') Reference
            , COALESCE(MA.PayrollRef, '') Payroll
            , Available.AvailableId 
        FROM
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                RequirerID
                , ShiftDate
                , CAST(ShiftStart - ShiftEnd - ShiftBreak AS DECIMAL(19,2)) ShiftDuration
                , Id RequirementRecordID
            FROM
                Requirements
            WHERE
                Requirements.ShiftDate BETWEEN @ParamStartDate
                AND @ParamEndDate
                AND RequirerID IN (SELECT ID FROM MemberDetails WHERE CompanyID = @ParamCompanyID)
            )
            R
            INNER JOIN
            ShiftConfirmed
            INNER JOIN
            Available
            INNER JOIN
            MemberDetails MA
            ON Available.AvailableID = MA.ID
            ON ShiftConfirmed.AvailableRecordID = Available.ID
            ON R.RequirementRecordID = ShiftConfirmed.RequirementRecordID
        WHERE
            R.ShiftDate BETWEEN @ParamStartDate
            AND @ParamEndDate
            AND COALESCE(ShiftChecked, 0) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
        )
        ShiftDay
    Group By
        Employee
        , Reference
        , Payroll
        , AvailableId
    ) Shifts
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT( * ) AS [Days]
        , AvailableID
    FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            R.ShiftDate
            , Available.AvailableId 
        FROM
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                ShiftDate
                , Id RequirementRecordID
            FROM
                Requirements
            WHERE
                Requirements.ShiftDate BETWEEN @ParamStartDate
                AND @ParamEndDate
                AND RequirerID IN (SELECT ID FROM MemberDetails WHERE CompanyID = @ParamCompanyID)
            )
            R
            INNER JOIN
            ShiftConfirmed
            INNER JOIN
            Available
            INNER JOIN
            MemberDetails MA
            ON Available.AvailableID = MA.ID
            ON ShiftConfirmed.AvailableRecordID = Available.ID
            ON R.RequirementRecordID = ShiftConfirmed.RequirementRecordID
        WHERE
            R.ShiftDate BETWEEN @ParamStartDate
            AND @ParamEndDate
            AND COALESCE(ShiftChecked, 0) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
        )
        ShiftDay
    Group By
        AvailableId
    ) D
    ON Shifts.AvailableID = D.AvailableID

WHERE [Hours] > 0
ORDER BY
    Employee
```